# XmlSchemaType "date" - without time zone?

Tags: java, xml, date, xsd, timezone

I am using java xml annotations like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OrganisationUnit", propOrder = {
        "companyId",
        "validFrom",
        "validTo",
})
public class OrganisationUnit {

    @XmlElement(name = "company_id", required = true)
    protected String companyId;

    @XmlElement(name = "valid_from")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar validFrom;

    @XmlElement(name = "valid_to")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar validTo;

    ...
}
```

However when I make the information available via a REST service, the `date` elements are displayed with time zones:

```
<organisationUnits>
    <organisationUnit>
         <company_id>ABC</company_id>
         <valid_from>1970-01-01+01:00</valid_from>
         <valid_to>2099-12-31+01:00</valid_to>
    </organisationUnit>
</organisationUnits>
```

I don't fully understand whether the XmlSchemaType `date` is required to show a time zone or not - but ideally I would like to show the dates without timezones.

```
         <valid_from>1970-01-01</valid_from>
         <valid_to>2099-12-31</valid_to>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, reading the documentation sometimes tells you wonderful things, and here's exactly how to do it, with time zone `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED`:

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar dateWithoutTimezone(Date date) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    calendar.setTime(date);
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
    xmlGregorianCalendar.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
    return xmlGregorianCalendar;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "reading the documentation sometimes tells you wonderful things" <3